# Not Getting Permission From User in MapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

Must call `-[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]` or `-[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` first. Actually i have called this method in Didload and even added in `info.plist` still getting this error.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"MapView";

    [MapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [MapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [MapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [MapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = 23.0804 ;
    region.center.longitude = 72.5241;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [MapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    [MapView setDelegate:self];

    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; //whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    Display *ann = [[Display alloc] init];
    ann.title = @" Gujarat";
    ann.subtitle = @"High Court";
    ann.coordinate = region.center;
    [MapView addAnnotation:ann];

}
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
    if(annotation != MapView.userLocation)
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[MapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                         initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.draggable = YES;
    }
    else {
        [MapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    }
    return pinView;
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status

{

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse)
    {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
    {
        //Alert to show for user if any when status is declined
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Wrong location status");
}
```

and in Display class for Annotation

```
<MKAnnotation> {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; 
    NSString *title; 
    NSString *subtitle;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
```

the code here doesn't show the prompt for permission  from user to access its location and because of this we don't get the location of desired place. Kindly, help me been on it since yesterday.

[image]

Comment: still getting this error. ...?

Comment: Yes still don't know where i m stucking

Comment: either call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization], but not both, as it doesnt make sense

Comment: as nick's answer doesn't help you for some reason, please provide a reduced sample app so we can save this

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iv5upqhmhmfr2yz/MapViewDemo.zip?dl=0 this is my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Actually There Was Two info.plist and i was changing values in Mapview Demo Test plist files. when i added the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in Info.plist   It Worked..

Answer (score 2):

Check below things in your app.

1) create a class object of CLLocation Manager. 
   Cause if your create a local object of CLLocation manager then the CLLocationManager object is released before the user responds to the dialog.

2) go to Settings > Privacy > Location Services. and check that is your app is listed in the list for location services. if yes then tap on your app and go inside check that the switch is ON.

3) check whether requestAlwaysAuthorization: is supported by using

```
if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

4) Try to check the status of location manager Using

```
-(void)checkStatus{

CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

if (status==kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
_status.text = @"Not Determined";
}

if (status==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
_status.text = @"Denied";
}

if (status==kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
_status.text = @"Restricted";
}

if (status==kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {
_status.text = @"Always Allowed";
}

if (status==kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
_status.text = @"When In Use Allowed";
  }

}
```

For more details please visit

1) http://www.devfright.com/location-authorization-ios-8/ 
2) http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/

Comment: i get the status Not determined

Comment: could you please check in Settings > Privacy > Location Services.  is your app is listed there ?

Also could you please try deleting app from simulator or device and load your app again.

Comment: still Not working i have checked even in setting and deleted multiple time.. what is the solution when location manager is not determined

Comment: hey have you make your cllocationmanager a global variable ? 

you can check my demo app.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x92puk6k2gnwczi/TestApp.zip?dl=0

Comment: Still location is not determined.. everything seems right

Comment: hi Narendra, here is your demo with corrected answer

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgszxq8hlev8uyj/MapViewDemo_Corrected.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

1. Declare `CLLocationManager *locationManager` as global variable. As the location manager will be released as scope ends. So the pop up to be shown for authorization will hide as soon as scope ends.
2. `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` should be written as soon as user authorize the status.

   ## import

   ## import

   ```
   @interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

   {
      CLLocationManager *locationManager;
   }

   @implementation ViewController
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad]; 

       [MapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
       [MapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
       [MapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
       [MapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
       MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
       region.center.latitude = 23.0804 ;
       region.center.longitude = 72.5241;
       region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
       region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
       [MapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

       locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
       locationManager.delegate = self;
       locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; //whenever we move
       locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;


       if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
       {
           [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
       }

       Display *ann = [[Display alloc] init];
       ann.title = @" Gujarat";
       ann.subtitle = @"High Court";
       ann.coordinate = region.center;
       [MapView addAnnotation:ann];
   }

   -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
           if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse)
           {
               [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
           }
           else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
           {
           //Alert to show for user if any when status is declined
           }
           else
               NSLog(@"Wrong location status");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

What i am able to see in your **.plist** *screenshot* is

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in Info.plist
```

is missing. This is for displaying prompt when your app is launched first time.
Adding these solves problem.

[image]

Comment: NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription i have added also that method and it's spelling is correct.. i have checked so many times..

Comment: Can you remove NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription from plist and try running by resetting simulator?

Comment: i have done that thing so many times. i even don't get user location by selecting at  run time (Debug).

Comment: Are you getting alert message first time when you installed? Also checking are you facing GPS location problem in real device or only simulator?

Comment: no i didnt get any alert message for accessing the location, we are facing GPS location problem